# building visual studio project

Tags: tortoisesvn, building

I'm pretty new with visual studio, and I've been emailed a vc++ project, but unable to build it. I think it has something to do with an external tool called SubWCRev. The initial errors led me to install TortoiseSVN since it appeared it was looking for it during the build process. Now, the build error says:

1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Building prodver.h"

The build log lists some batch commands that deal with this tool, and basically just lists the above error again. I don't think I really need this tool, and I've tried to prevent it from running by modifying the .vcproj file. I basically commented out the lines in the file referring to subwcrev, but it didn't change the behavior at all. The same error occurs.

I'm using visual studio express 2008 on 32 bit xp, and the project was originally built with VS2008 as well.

Does anyone have any ideas either how to prevent this tool from being run or if I'm way off in troubleshooting this?

Comment: Actually I think we figured it out. I was given two header files, version.h and prodver.h that were pre-built, and I removed two files from the project tree called version.in and prodver.in. This seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Based strictly on that, it looks like SubWCRev (which is a tool included in TortoiseSVN) is used to create the file "prodver.h" (product version, most likely). That file is more than likely referenced elsewhere, so just removing the SubWCRev step is unlikely to solve your problems. In addition, if you don't have a Subversion working copy of the code, SubWCRev won't work in any case.

One possible solution would be to manually create the "prodver.h" file, then eliminate the build step(s) that call SubWCRev.